# Nitrous.io to github connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nitrousio

I am using Nitrous.io for Ruby on Rails development and am trying to connect with GitHub. I am running into this error when I connect to GitHub. Does anyone know what the solution to this is? It happens immediately once clicked "Connect to Github". I did try it and then canceled the first time because I entered the wrong information for my github login. Now whenever I try to go to connect to Git, it doesn't work. This is all that renders in the browser...

{"error":"state_mismatch","error_description":"state provided does not match cookie state"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently an issue connecting to Github when you login through https://www.nitrous.io.

Try logging in through the domain [https://pro.nitrous.io/](https://pro.nitrous.io), and from there you can [connect to Github](https://community.nitrous.io/docs/connect-to-github).

Comment: I don't know how that worked but that worked for me. Now to figure out how to actually use my repositories lol. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you added the wrong remote. You have to delete and set it correctly: `git remote remove origin`. What info did you improperly set?

These are the steps for Nitrous.io:

First add SSH keys: https://community.nitrous.io/docs/connect-to-github. Then create a repo on your github account (https://github.com/new). Then run `git init`, then

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# Set a new remote: your remote. 

$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git push origin master
```